# android:play audio files and display images dynamically

Tags: android, media-player

Hi guys i am having 3 audio files and three images with three text displaying for each image.
Now what i have done as soon as application starts the first image,text and audio file starts playing and after completion of that 2nd one starts similarly 3rd one starts.

Basically i need these to played sequentially one after the other but dynamically since i am having some 20 files similar to this

below is my code

```
public class S001Activity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    ImageView img;
    TextView display;
    MediaPlayer apple = new MediaPlayer();
    MediaPlayer boy = new MediaPlayer();
    MediaPlayer cat = new MediaPlayer();
    //Runnable rb,rc;

    Document doc;
    DocumentBuilder builder;
    Handler handler = new Handler();

    int i=0;
    int noOfQues = 0;
    //int media[] = {R.raw.apple_v,R.raw.boy_v,R.raw.cat_v};
    //int image[] = {R.drawable.apple,R.drawable.boy,R.drawable.cat};

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
        display = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.display);

        img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.apple);
        apple = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.apple_v);
        apple.start();
        xml();


        boy = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.boy_v);

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                i++;
                img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.boy);

                boy.start();
                xml();
            }
        },apple.getDuration()+ 2000 );

        cat = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.cat_v);
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                i++;
                img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cat);
                cat.start();
                xml();
            }
        },apple.getDuration()+ boy.getDuration()+ 2000 );
}


    public void xml(){
         try {
            InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.topic1761);
            builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
            doc = builder.parse(in, null);

            NodeList listOfPersons = doc.getElementsByTagName("Point");
            noOfQues = listOfPersons.getLength();
            System.out.println("items======= " + noOfQues);

            Node firstPersonNode = listOfPersons.item(i);

            Element firstPersonElement = (Element) firstPersonNode;

            NodeList firstNameList = firstPersonElement.getElementsByTagName("PracticeText");
            Element firstNameElement = (Element) firstNameList.item(0);

            NodeList textFNList = firstNameElement.getChildNodes();
            display.setText(((Node) textFNList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());

        } catch (Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Exception: " + t.toString(), 2000).show();
        }
    }
```

edited code

```
@Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mps) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //MediaPlayer mps = new MediaPlayer();

        img.setBackgroundResource(image[i]);
        handler.post(new Runnable() {

              @Override
              public void run() {

                  xml();
                  AssetFileDescriptor afd = getResources().openRawResourceFd(media[i]);
                  mp.reset();
                  try {
                    mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor());
                    afd.close();
                    mp.prepare();
                    mp.start();

                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

              }
             });  
    }
```

Comment: i didnt get you can you come again

Comment: you want to extend your logic to support more files? i.e. 3 to 20?

Comment: yes karthik you are exactly right

Comment: @Varun i think you and me doing same app..

Comment: well fine but have got the logic if got plz help

Comment: i am useing touchlistener in activity A a image is displayed touch the image a sound is come.this my app what about your app?

Comment: our app is completely different it plays audio and displays images sequentially u could have used onclick only instead of ontouch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use array or a list to store the list of music files, image files and text.
Then play the next one in [MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener.html).

**EDIT:**

```
int media[] = {R.raw.apple_v,R.raw.boy_v,R.raw.cat_v};
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();

// in OnCompletionListener,
index = index + 1; //add proper checks
handler.post(new Runnable() {

  @Override
  public void run() {
      AssetFileDescriptor afd = getResources().openRawResourceFd(media[index]);
      mp.reset();
      mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor());
      afd.close();
      mp.prepare();
      mp.start();
  }
 });
```

I think you can get the idea with the above sample code.

Comment: can you please provide me with some example i tried like this but it didnt work int media[] = {R.raw.apple_v,R.raw.boy_v,R.raw.cat_v};

Comment: setdatasource called in state 16 please help

Comment: you have to call reset before calling setDataSource().

Comment: Karthik now i have tried but what is happining is only one image is being displayed but audio files is looping or playing twice

Comment: where is your EDIT? i'm not able to see. audio files looping maybe because of `setLooping()`. make sure you reuse the same mediaplayer instance, don't create new ones for each file.

Comment: karthik now what is happining is audio files are playing sequentially but images are not changing i have used this code in oncompletion listener img.setBackgroundResource(image[i]);

Comment: I think you should use [setImageResource()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource(int)), not setBackgroundResource().

Comment: if it solves your problem, then do accept the answer. Anybody else searching for similar issue will find it useful.

Comment: I am getting - setDataSource called in state 16. What does it mean actually?!?

Comment: @Imon, if it is part of `IllegalStateException` then you are calling `setDataSource` in an invalid state. I'm not sure what _16_ means.